# BlenRig Cage Hip Collapsing

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature

I've started working with BlenRig for my characters and It was going really well until i got to the hips.

The Left hip has no problem, it will stretch out as far as I want.
The right works good too:
[image: Symmetrical]

So whats the problem? I work with these measurements:

Units: Meters

Length: Metric

Angle: Degrees

Unit Scale: 0.01

Therefore I must scale the rig up a fair amount.( and yes I am using Reporportion. I have also tried scaling in Object Mode and the result is a pancaked cage.) That's when this happens:
[image]

This ONLY effects the hips. I've caged the model with all other parts, but the hip just does not work.

Is there any why to fix this? What is odd-er still is that X-Axis Mirror still functions even with the mesh messing up like this.
[image]